# How to use jquery in Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

I have developed small project using Angular 6 and ASP .Net MVC 5 with Rest API.
I was trying to use jquery functions like datepicker and datatable which I am not able to use in it.

I have used following steps :-

```
npm install jquery —save
```

in Angular.json :-

```
"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ] 

in typescript file :-
import * as $ from 'jquery';

ngOnInit() {  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
      $("#demo").datepicker({  
        dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"  
       });  
    });  
  }
```

I am getting an error when I am running the above code.
Please let me know the solution to this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: "getting error " what error _exactly_? [mcve]

Comment: simple as that: DONT!

Comment: If use just want to use datepicker and datatable u can make use of angular packages itself.working with jquery without proper kknowledge can raise change detection issue in future.

Comment: and still if you want to use jquery means,First try your jquery is imported properly by console log $ in on init and see if thats defined.if not your import has some issues

Comment: @msanford  $("#demo").datepicker() is not a function This error is coming

Comment: @NambiNRajan other functions like click is working fine but datetime is giving error.  $("#demo").datepicker() is not a function This error is coming

Comment: I would suggest using Angular Material implementations given they have datepicker and datatables already: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview and https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview. If those don't meet your requirements, you can use other Angular compatible libraries, PrimeNG springs to mind: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/

Comment: carme try running this line of code in chrom console after page loaded completely.
$("#demo").datepicker() .
and move this function to afterviewInit your view might not be initialized at the time this funvtion is called

Comment: As I recall, Datepicker is in JQuery UI not JQuery. So you are missing dependencies. That said to everyone else, although this is far from ideal (Jquery in Angular) someone should assume there is a reason, and not only discourage JQuery. (That said, if you can avoid JQuery, do avoid it)

Comment: ok i will check . Thank you all for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Like everyone said you should not use Jquery in Angular. Angular Material provide very good built-in components for  date picking, you should take a look.
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

However to help you with your issue, try using an absolute path in angular.json

```
"scripts": [ "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a tool.
Like every tool you have to know when, where, and how you can use it.

It is NOT wrong to use it in an Angular application, you just have to have a good reason for it.

Per se, a datepicker is not a good reason because as many already told you, you could use Angular Material or one of the many libraries around the web.

With that out of my chest,

```
 $("#demo").datepicker({  
    dateFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd"  
   });
```

This cannot work for a simple reason: "datepicker" is not defined in JQuery, it is defined in JQuery UI https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Add JQuery UI to your scripts and you should be good to go.
I also don't recommend using the

```
$(document).ready
```

Function as you can easily use one of Angular's lifecycle events. ngOnInit is probably good enough in your case